# Bind9 - forward all queries excluding one domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have following simple bind9 configuration

```
acl "allowed" { 127.0.0.1/8; 192.168.0.1/24; };

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    forward only;
    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };

    allow-query { "allowed"; };

    auth-nxdomain no;
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Now I'd like to change the forwarder to forward all DNS queries except ones related to the domain uribl.com which should be queried directly.
Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want disable the global forwarding configuration for uribl.com you need overrides the global configuration settings with:

```
zone "uribl.com" {
       type forward;
       forwarders {};
};
```

**type:** If no forwarders statement is present or an empty list is provided then no forwarding will be done for the domain canceling the effects of any forwarders in the options clause

[Documentation](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/zone.html#type)